# Swift Compiler Error: Type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' has no subscript members

Tags: swift, xcode, moltin

I'm currently making an ecommerce app in Swift 4 and linking data with Moltin. I'm doing this for school so I'm new at this. I'm also following CodeWithChris's tutorial but that is out of date and my layout is a bit different. I followed everything on it but I'm getting this error:

> Type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' has no subscript members

I don't understand why.

```
self.objects = responseDictionary["result"] as? [AnyObject]
```

I tried changing `as?` to `as!` and it still didn't work.

Here's my complete code;

```
import UIKit
import Moltin

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
var objects = [AnyObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   Moltin.sharedInstance().setPublicID('***my store ID***')

    Moltin.sharedInstance().product.listing(withParameters: nil, success: { (responseDictionary) in
        self.objects = responseDictionary["result"] as? [AnyObject]

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }) { (responseDictionary, error) in
        print ("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```

Comment: `[AnyHashable : Any]?` aka `Optional<[AnyHashable : Any]>` doesn't have subscript members, `[AnyHashable : Any]` on other hand does.

Answer (score 1):

`responseDictionary` appears to be an optional which needs to be checked for existence:

```
Moltin.sharedInstance().product.listing(withParameters: nil, success: { (response) in
    guard let responseDictionary = response as? [AnyHashable : Any] else {
        print("Error: respnonse is empty")
        return
    }

    self.objects = responseDictionary["result"] as? [AnyObject]

   // ...
}
```

Comment: Or, if you're using `as?` and expect an optional back anyway, you can just do `self.objects = response?["result"] as? [AnyObject]`